# how can i pass function or function array props in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

```
props: {
    onClick: {
         type: [Function as PropType<(...args) => any>,Array as PropType<((...args) => any)[]>],
         default: null
    }

}
```

I want to pass a function or array function like [fnc1, func2]，but when i pass [func1, func2] it always check failed with a warn 'Expected a Function but got Array', how can i fixed this

Comment: Passing functions to a component in vue is actually an anti-pattern and should generally be avoided. Instead you should use emits and then call your function when that emit event happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Options API`:

```
onClick: {
  type: Array,
  validator: (value) => {
    return Array.isArray(value) && value.every((handler) => typeof handler === 'function')
  },
},
```

If you are using the `Composition API` and `script setup`, try this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface IProps {
  onClick: Array<() => void>
}

const props = defineProps<IProps>()
</script>
```